# Python Error when using json.load on the same file again

Tags: python, json

The error occurs if I try to convert the json file into a variable and try to convert the file again to a separate variable is throws and error.  I thought that json.load converts a json object to the python equivalent.  So I am confused on why calling json.load(file) again would cause an error.  Is the file still open or being used by the first call?  I know I can get around it, I am just trying to understand json and the error.
Using python 3.9.

#This code works:

```
def scores2(filedir):
    for filename in os.listdir(filedir):
        with open(os.path.join(filedir, filename), 'r') as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)
```

#This code with the extra conversion to a new variable fails with error

```
def scores2(filedir):
    for filename in os.listdir(filedir):
        with open(os.path.join(filedir, filename), 'r') as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)
            dataextra= json.load(read_file)
```

The error is raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: `read_file` is a stream, so after looping over it once, the second loop starts at the end of the file and doesn't do anything. You can try `read_file.readlines()` to load everything into memory or check other questions on this topic

Comment: As shriakhilc mentioned the first read leaves the file positioned at the end hence the error.  can you give sample or actual data from the file?  if you have say 2 lines of json in one file then you can read each line and pass it off to json.loads().

Comment: Typically json in a file will be a dump of one complete python object and its nested members.

Comment: Thanks shriakhilc and LhasaDad.  I am still learning .   So a file-like-object maintains a state tracking where it is in the file. After the last bit of data is read, each successive call  returns the empty string. The stream is exhausted.  I was thinking the json.load was creating a new link or resetting it, but its the open()  that creates the stream.  thanks for the help and direction.

Answer (score 3):

In your second set of code, the first json.load() reads all of the data in the file and leaves the read pointer at the end of the file. the subsequent .load() call gets a empty string which results in the error you get.   You either need to:

1. have your two json blobs in different files and read them separately or
2. you need to use loads() to load the json object from a string and manage the data in the file with read operations that read part of the file that contains the individual sections of json. you would read the data in as a string then pass it to loads()